# How can i use if condition in Numpy Sum

Tags: python

I have array show below

```
arr =np.array([85,22,3,24,56,89,84,15,1,45,1,40,65])
```

I want to do total sum of value which is less than 25.

I know that i can do

```
total_price = 0
for x in arr:
    if x < 25:
        total_price += x
```

but is there something like `sum(arr, i <25)` which will return total sum value which is less than 25?in c++ there lambda function can i do such thing in python?how can i use numpy sum? is it better to use numpy lib?

Comment: where is numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([85,22,3,24,56,89,84,15,1,45,1,40,65])

>>> arr[arr<25].sum()

66
```

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz. this is what i was looking for.